# Restangular: Failed requests stops execution with await

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-promise, restangular, ngx-restangular

I have an error interceptor like below:

```
RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response) => {

    const error = EnumerableFromObject(response.error.Errors)
      .Select(i => i.Value.Message)
      .FirstOrDefault();
    toastr.error(error, "Error");

    return true;
  });
}
```

Below is the code of my auth service:

```
  async Login(login: string, password: string) {
    const sessions = this.rest.all("sessions");
    const params = {Login: login,Password: password };
    const response = await sessions.post(params).toPromise();
    return response;
  }
```

And this is how I am calling it in my component:

```
this.loader.show();
const response = await this.authorizationService.Login(login, password);
this.loader.hide();
```

So I have to hide loader after the service is completed, failed or not.

My issue is when a request fails with any reason - like wrong credentials - execution stops, & it never reaches to `this.loader.hide();`

How can I handle this without using `then`. In my project all methods are called with `await`. So I can't remove await & use then. It will require so much rework.

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you do not have any error handling in place. If your request fails the `await` part will throw an exception - that means the function is exited --> your `.hide()` call is never reached

To handle this you can wrap it inside a try catch, e.g.

```
this.loader.show();
try {
    const response = await this.authorizationService.Login(login, password);
} catch (error) {
    // do something with the error here
}
this.loader.hide();
```